# AWS-CLI EC2 AMI :: Get details about owner via OwnerId

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-ec2

Given the `OwnerId` field returned from an  AWS ami query such as:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids ami-015f906ef3e2123c0 --region ap-southeast-2 --query Images[].OwnerId
[
    "602401143452"
]
```

how can I retrieve some information about who the owner *actually is*. The `OwnerId` means nothing to me.